# Separate "domains" in LoopBack

Tags: loopbackjs

I am designing a loopBack based WEB app with an architecture similar to this one:

[image]

This server should serve several different client sysstems in addition to the frontend app. Each one of the external system will have its own REST API available, with different resources, auth, etc. I would like to separate those "REST domains" neatly.

I would like all those APIs to have different routes, like this:

base-url/frontend  (this is easy)
base-url/system-1/.....
base-url/system-2/.....

What is the cleanest way to do this in LoopBack?

loopBack models in an app are created all in the same place and I can only specify their name. Is there a way to change the default URL of a model?
What if I have a model with the same name in both systems?

Comment: What is intersect between these 3 systems from backend view?

Comment: There is some logic, but not so relevant for the problem. I'm just wondering how to segment REST endpoints in different groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this by using loopback router if base url is same
For e.g if you handling get request

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  var router = app.loopback.Router();

    router.get('/frontend/some-api', function (req, res) {
      // you can call your model method responsible to serve this request
    }
    router.get('/system-1/some-api', function (req, res) {
      // you can call your model method responsible to serve this request
    }
    router.get('/system-2/some-api', function (req, res) {
      // you can call your model method responsible to serve this request
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds good. I would just replace router.get(...) with router.use(...), so that complete traffic is dispatched to domain specific middleware for further processing. Is there a way in loopback to do this configuring some JSON file? If not, what is the most appropriate place to put this code in?

Comment: root.js file is appropriate place to put this code. Its present in server/boot/   directory which is created default by loopback Application generator